# Intermediate field of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree 4 over $\Bbb Q$ and $Gal(f)=S_4$.

Prove that there isn't nontrivial intermediate field between $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $E$ be a splitting field of $f$. Then, $[E:\Bbb Q]=24$.

If there is such intermediate field $K$, then clearly $[E:K]=12$, which means $Gal(E/K)=A_4$.

But it's impossible? Or should I do different way by using irreducibility of $f$?

Comment: You are well on your way. +1 for that and explaining your thinking! The catch is that $Gal(E/\Bbb{Q}(\alpha))= S_3$, i.e. a point stabilizer inside $S_4$. But $A_4$ does not contain any of the four point stabilizers. See the question I proffer as a duplicate for details (and a generalization).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, thanks very much!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah, I had to think about $Gal(E/\Bbb Q(\alpha))$.... I should bear in mind :)